# too many libraries when loading error, Chromium compile for Android4.2.2

Tags: android, chromium

I followed this to compile Chromium ( Actually I need content_shell_apk):
https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/android-build-instructions

Compilation of both ChromePublic.APK and ContentShell.apk succefull, but when I run them in my Android 4.2.2 device, I get this error:
https://paste2.org/nxFYVvtW

```
Cannot load library: soinfo_alloc(linker.cpp:287): too many libraries when loading "libEGL_mali.so"
```

I am searching for 2 days, and only thing I could find is this:
comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.chromium.devel/43328

How should I get rid of this error, and compile official ContentShell.apk for my device?

Comment: Are you loading any .so files manually ?.

Comment: No I am not. Should I ?

Comment: No I was just checking.. Usually this error happens when you try to load a .so file.Don't know what is causing issue for you..

Comment: Ok, thanks for your guess. I am searching whole internet to find a clue, but I just can't find anything. I understand that it is related with the limit of Android libc to load max number of *so files at a time, but I don't know how to increase behaviour of Chromium to change it. For my case, it could be loading those libraries statically, but I can't find how to link all those so files statically either...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved. Somehow, my out/Default directory was corrupted.

I removed that directory, and run GN configuration again:

```
gn args out/Default
```

At this point, to make sure that there are no any debug symbols included:

```
target_os = "android"
target_cpu = "arm"  
is_debug = false  

is_component_build = false
is_clang = true
symbol_level = 1
```

After that, generated filesize for ContentShell.apk is around 40Mbytes ( Jan.2017 ), and it runs perfectly on Android 4.2.2 .

To be able to modify user interface, someone can edit shell_view.xml which is at:

```
./content/shell/android/java/res/layout/shell_view.xml
```

There are also a few java files, which can be edited easily, and make your own browser for your custom android device :)

Many thanks to people at #chromium for IRC help.